# How other websites detect that you are logged in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, session-cookies

If a user is logged in facebook how will i detect that im my website? how does iframe takes care of it. I need methods beside iframe.

Comment: Is your question answered here?  http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=62770

Comment: Think they just try to load an image of the facebook site that can only be seen by who is logged in, if the image is successfuly loaded then you're logged in, otherwise you're not.

Comment: @Delta [Like this, right?](https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Javascript SDK:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(response.session){
        //user is logged in
    }else{
        //user not logged in
    }
});
```